# socketio client not connected on ubunto server with sockeio client for ios

Tags: ios, node.js, swift, websocket, socket.io

I have this api that locally running on windows 10 listen a socket with a namespace  "vendedores" at windows station i can connet form ios app

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        let myJSON = [
            "lng":String(location.coordinate.longitude),
            "lat":String(location.coordinate.latitude),
            "idvendedor":appDelegate.idSeller
        ]
        print("updating location")

        let socket = SocketIOClient(socketURL: URL(string: self.constans.addres)!,config: [.connectParams(["accessToken" : appDelegate.token]),.forcePolling(true),.nsp("/vendedor"), .log(true)])
        print("el url del token: \(self.constans.addres)/vendedor")

        socket.on("connect") {data, ack in
            print("socket connected")
            socket.emit("setLocation",myJSON)
            print("Mostrando el Json: \(myJSON)")
        }
        socket.on("locationChanged", callback: {_,_ in
            print("disconnected")
            socket.disconnect()
        })
        print("send to connect ")
        socket.connect()
```

on server side running on node have this code

```
vendedorSocket.on('connection', function (socket) {
        console.log('Un vendedor se ha conectado');
        socket.on('setLocation', function(data){
            try{
                    assert(data.lng, "No longitude provided.");
                    assert(data.lat, "No latitude provided");
                    assert(data.idvendedor, "No idvendedor provided");
                    console.log('Ha cambiado la ubicación de un vendedor');
                    app.models.mapa.find({where: {vendedorId: data.idvendedor, activa: true }}, function(err, ubicaciones_inst) {
                        if (err) throw(err);
                        if(ubicaciones_inst && ubicaciones_inst.length > 0){
                            ubicaciones_inst.forEach(function (ubicacion) {
                                ubicacion.activa = false;
                                ubicacion.save();
                            });
                        }
                    });
                    var geopoint = {lat: data.lat, lng: data.lng};
                    app.models.mapa.create({coordenadas: geopoint, activa: true, vendedorId: data.idvendedor, created: Date.now()}, function(err, ubicacion_inst){
                        if(err) throw(err);
                        else if(ubicacion_inst){
                            socket.emit('locationChanged', ubicacion_inst);
                        }
                    });
            }
            catch(ex){
                throwSocketException(socket, ex.message);
            }
        });
    });
```

after conection to the local api i´ve got response from api socket connected and in deed in db there some data sent to the service with location data. 
but when running the app with the service running on the cloud the socket never get connected this the log shown in xcode

> 2017-09-18 12:07:03.802 vasoking[1036:26086] LOG SocketEnginePolling:
>   Got poll message: 1:3 2017-09-18 12:07:03.808 vasoking[1036:26086] LOG
>   SocketEngine: Got message: 3 2017-09-18 12:07:03.812
>   vasoking[1036:26086] LOG SocketEnginePolling: Doing polling GET
>   http://192.241.223.xxx:8003/socket.io/?transport=polling&b64=1&accessToken=ISWp70VbUX7YfHLHzs3ayYySADhWeMnT1k94Vuwsn1g2zr069lvyBV7JTOVEyEYj&sid=rGP6Zohesfhk0yE9AAAT
>   2017-09-18 12:07:06.100 vasoking[1036:25994] LOG SocketEngine: Writing
>   poll:  has data: false 2017-09-18 12:07:06.100 vasoking[1036:25817]
>   LOG SocketEngine: Writing poll:  has data: false 2017-09-18
>   12:07:06.106 vasoking[1036:25994] LOG SocketEnginePolling: Sending
>   poll:  as type: 2 2017-09-18 12:07:06.107 vasoking[1036:25817] LOG
>   SocketEnginePolling: Sending poll:  as type: 2 2017-09-18 12:07:06.108
>   vasoking[1036:25994] LOG SocketEnginePolling: Created POST string: 1:2
>   2017-09-18 12:07:06.110 vasoking[1036:25817] LOG SocketEnginePolling:
>   Created POST string: 1:2 2017-09-18 12:07:06.113 vasoking[1036:25994]
>   LOG SocketEnginePolling: POSTing 2017-09-18 12:07:06.114
>   vasoking[1036:25817] LOG SocketEnginePolling: POSTing 2017-09-18
>   12:07:06.117 vasoking[1036:25994] LOG SocketEnginePolling: Doing
>   polling POST
>   http://192.241.223.xxx:8003/socket.io/?transport=polling&b64=1&accessToken=ISWp70VbUX7YfHLHzs3ayYySADhWeMnT1k94Vuwsn1g2zr069lvyBV7JTOVEyEYj&sid=eBFLEj9Lyq5gFsOTAAAX
>   2017-09-18 12:07:06.119 vasoking[1036:25817] LOG SocketEnginePolling:
>   Doing polling POST
>   http://192.241.223.xxx:8003/socket.io/?transport=polling&b64=1&accessToken=ISWp70VbUX7YfHLHzs3ayYySADhWeMnT1k94Vuwsn1g2zr069lvyBV7JTOVEyEYj&sid=tqm-6Kb6cYkK5XxlAAAY

So no data is transmited and of course no answer from server so what could be the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

following this link https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift/issues/744 
In SocketIOClient.swift, when I put this piece of code in

```
open func engineDidOpen(reason: String):
if reason == "Connect" {
joinNamespace(nsp)
}
```

voila this works perfect, i guess that is a problem between windows and linux server running node because without this on windows get connected and with it also, but linux server without this does not connect to namespace